# what is the variable scope in python, when you define a variable in the function argument list?

Tags: function, variables, scope, python-2.x

Finally, I got a question that I cannot find on stackoverflow.

So I was fiddling around with python and spark when I saw this weird behavior and could not figure out why it was behaving like that?

Here is what I observed

when I write a function like this

```
>>> def add_to_q(n,q=[]):
...      q+=[n]
...      return q

>>> add_to_q(1)
[1]
>>> add_to_q(2)
[1,2]
```

Here the variable "q" in not initiated again as an empty list, but the same queue reference was used each time I called the function.

But when I try to achieve the same with a variable like this,

```
>>> def add_to_sum(n, sum=0)
...     sum += n
...     return sum

>>> add_to_sum(1)
1
>>> add_to_sum(5)
5
```

It should have returned 6 to be in sync with the previous example but it did not. What happened?

What is the difference between ho python handle a list and a variable?

Why is this useful in a list, and not a variable. ?

Thank you in advance for any help or leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects of built-in types like (int, float, bool, str, tuple, unicode) are immutable. Objects of built-in types like (list, set, dict) are mutable. Custom classes are generally mutable.

Mutable objects are great to use when you need to change the size of the object, example list, dict etc.. Immutables are used when you need to ensure that the object you made will always stay the same.Immutable objects are fundamentally expensive to “change”, because doing so involves creating a copy. Changing mutable objects is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable,hence python can make changes in the list every time the function is called.Because of this the changes are carried over.
But integers are not mutable, hence python creates a new reference every time the function is called, hence the changes are not carried over.